# when using existing template in fpdf/fpdfi displays only the size of the file

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, fpdf

How can I use existing template in fpdf. I have already used fpdi and can generate a pdf but the thing is, it didn't use the source file. It only display the size of the file and the additional text I have added. Here's the code I've tried:

```
public function template_trial(){

$this->load->library('fpdf'); 
$this->load->library('fpdi'); 

$pdf = new FPDI();
// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
// set the source file
$pdf->setSourceFile("test.pdf");
// import page 1
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
// use the imported page and place it at point 10,10 with a width of 100 mm
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, 0, 0, true);
// now write some text above the imported page
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
$pdf->SetTextColor(255, 0, 0);
$pdf->SetXY(30, 30);
$pdf->Write(0, 'This is just a simple text');
$pdf->Output('tes.pdf','D');
}
```

**sample text in pdf:**

The file size of this PDF is only 12 KB.
This is just a simple text

Comment: Could you isolate this issue into e.g. a zip-package so we can reproduce this? What versions of FPDF and FPDI are you usign?

Comment: @Setasign, I am using fpdi 1.5.4 and fpdf 1.7

Comment: @Setasign, I am actually using codeigniter with these libraries FPDF and FPDI.

Comment: @Setasign, Upon checking the whole thing, I found out that I have set an invalid file path. I'm sorry for the inconvenience and thank you.

Comment: so my guess to a version issue was correct?

Comment: @Setasign, yes it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('c','A4','','',11,10,20,10,10,10);
$mpdf->SetImportUse();
$mpdf->SetDocTemplate('layout_bb.compressed.pdf',true); // Add Template
$mpdf->AddPage();

$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion = true;
$mpdf->charset_in = 'utf-8';
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html); // Put my content on page
$mpdf->Output();
```